# Windows Phone 8 skydrive backup isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-8, backup, restore, isolatedstorage, onedrive

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 application, that saves its data into isolated storage (text,images,...)

I would like to create a backup to SkyDrive functionality with recovery and I want to ask if I can simply backup the Isolated Storage as whole, and recover it?

The procedure will be:
(1) generate a file (like zip) containing the whole Isolated Storage, 
(2) upload that to SkyDrive, 
(3) downloading from SkyDrive and 
(4) replacing data from downloaded file to any existing files in the storage.